# How to Start/stop/restart Apache Process using PHP

Tags: php, apache, process, xampp

We want to kill Currently running Apache process using PHP, i am using windows machine with XAMPP server.

I am building application which need to restart Apache automatically after 5 hours , so thought of using PHP coding to stop all existing process of apache and than start again.

Please advise me if anybody has other solution.

Comment: system() function may help you

Comment: exec() function is an option http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: `system()` and `exec()` is the only way I can think of. But the PHP process needs to run as a user who can do this (usually only root can) and letting a PHP script run as root is not a good idea as long as it is public. Inside a cron job I think there is no problem.

Comment: no `cron` on windows. Test your PHP script from PHP CLI and use `Scheduled Tasks` to run your command.

Comment: System() and exec() is not helping me, can anybody suggest some other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinXP SP3 here with xAMPP v1.8.1 VC9:

Other option:
 Just use `apache_stop.bat` & `apache_start.bat` scripts provided with xAMPP windows stack. Test with `Scheduled Tasks`; there is option `Run as` choose an admin account.

Comment: look goood, i will go ahead try above process, Thanks in advance